# Sharp edge with custom drawable clip path

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-custom-drawable

I am trying to draw a circular drawable which consists of horizontal divisions of different color.
But the circular path that i clip from the drawable creates a circle which has broken circumference.[image: drawable]

Here is the snippet for onDraw() from Drawable

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

    // get drawable dimensions
    Rect bounds = getBounds();

    int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.addCircle(width/2, height/2, width/2, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);

    int barHeight = height / themeColors.length;
    mRectF.left = 0;
    mRectF.top = 0;
    mRectF.right = width;
    mRectF.bottom = height;
    //Draw Rect. consisting of multiple rects acc. to height
    for (int i = 0; i < themeColors.length; i++) {
        mPaint.setColor(themeColors[i]);

        canvas.drawRect(0, i*barHeight, width, (i+1)*barHeight , mPaint);
    }

    //Draw stroke border
    if(mStrokeWidth!=0)
        canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, width/2, mStrokePaint);

}
```

How do i go about developing the drawable such that the edges are smooth ?
Can this be done with just xml drawable ?

EDIT:
I tried using PorterDuff modes with paint, but they did not work as given.

Comment: what is your problem actually? what `"broken circumference"` do you mean?

Comment: The border of the drawable is not smooth due to clipping of the drawable as you can see in the attached image. It will be visible if you zoom in.

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/6PLmXLXX

Comment: Well hello there..

Comment: @pskink the border does look  smooth now. Could you please post it as an answer and explain what you did. Thanks !